# Is it possible to know which of .NET code created a temporary file?

Tags: c#, .net, file, temporary-files

I'm reviewing a Windows Azure web role VM an I see that the temporary folder of the process running the role payload contains several dozen temporary files of zero length created some long time ago. This is a potential problem for me because if files are created and left over in uncontrolled manner the role gets trashed at some point.

I'm in full control of the payload code and there's good chance that those temporary files are created by the same process that runs the payload.

Is it possible to intercept temporary files creation from C# code running in the same process as the process creating the files?

Comment: Are you asking how to verify that the temporary files are created from your particular process, how to stop that, or both? For the first, take a look at [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), not specific to .NET. As for how to stop it, personally, I would normally first look more closely how and why they're getting created, so I don't have an answer for that, at least not right now.

Comment: @hvd: No, I want a callstack for each such creation so that I know if that's my code (then I fix it) or the host code (then I ask Microsoft to fix it).

Comment: I think procmon can capture managed call stacks. I t can capture natives one for sure (and always does).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a debugger (remote/otherwise) and live dumps to get this information?

You can always try

- to use FileSystemWatcher to throw an exception at the time a temp file is created. Use the debugger (Ctl+Alt+E in VS for exception dialog) to trap on first-chance exceptions. You can then inspect the stack for the other threads
- to use system audit policies (this will only tell you what user and perhaps (?) process created a file. (See also http://www.techrepublic.com/article/step-by-step-how-to-audit-file-and-folder-access-to-improve-windows-2000-pro-security/5034308)

[image]

- Eliminate by tagging your own file creations with extra information (e.g. write their names to a log file, create `.tag` files for each file written etc)